# Is there any default function in C++ to search for a word in a string?

Tags: c++, c, string

Is there any default function in C++ to search for a word in a string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [`string::find()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/)

Answer (score 3):

That would be [`strstr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9da80kz.aspx) if you want a plain function to work with `char*`, [`std::string::find`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/efzty53k.aspx) if you work with `std::string`.

Comment: @alan: You have tagged the question `C` and you ask about .net, which is completely unrelated. What exactly are you programming in?

Comment: dude, .NET has a library to work with C. It's famous. But in my case i'm not using .net. Your answer is good thanks.